# Prevent form reloading from parent to child in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from my child component (who has the form), to the parent component using a callback function, but I can't use the event.preventDefault() from the parent function, my code is the next:

```
function handleSubmit (event) {
    console.log("Done")
    event.preventDefault()
}

<LoginForm onFormSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
```

And this is my child form component:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
})

function handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target

    setCurrentUser(prevValue => {
        if (name === "email") {
            return {
                username: value,
                password: prevValue.password
            };
        } else if (name === "password") {
            return {
                username: prevValue.username,
                password: value
            };
        }
    })
}

    <form
         onSubmit={() => props.onFormSubmit()}
         className={classes.form}>
                <TextField
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    id="email"
                    label="Email Address"
                    name="email"
                    value={currentUser.username}
                />
                <TextField
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    id="password"
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    value={currentUser.password}
                />
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                >
    </form>
```

So my question is, how can I prevent the form from reloading, and how can I pass the currentUser values to the parent component, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing event `e` from child component:

```
<form
  onSubmit={e => {
    // e.preventDefault(); 
    props.onFormSubmit(); // You didn't pass e
  }}
>
  <TextField
    onChange={handleChange}

    // .... 

</form>
```

but expecting it in parent's handler:

```
function handleSubmit (event) {
    console.log("Done")
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

So, either pass the event `e` from child or use `e.preventDefault()` in the child itself as shown above. And to pass the form data back to parent, you should pass `currentUser` and handle it in parent.

```
  onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onFormSubmit(currentUser);
  }}
```

In parent:

```
function handleSubmit (data) {
    console.log("Done", data)
    // do something with data, e.g. make API call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As parent re-renders it will cause child to re-render. You can prevent this using `React.memo()` it does shallow comparison with previous & incoming `props` and determine whether to render or not.

Example child component:

```
const ChildComp = React.memo(
   ({pristineForm}) => <div>Child component</div>
)
```

`pristineForm` is initially `true` if you make it `false` after updating parent state child will not re-render.